# Rendering one pixel using DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx11

is it possible to render one pixel using DirectX 11? if its possible how to do it ?

Comment: You can draw a single point and then swap, but why would you do that?

Comment: I want to write a software render using DirectX11 just for learning purposes. but what do you mean by drawing a single point and then swap ?

Comment: Just render a point.

Comment: You sadly can't learn anything from creating a softwer renderer that's not obsolete or useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to use a DYNAMIC 2D texture, and each 'frame' copy from a 2D array in system memory that your software renderer produces to the DYNAMIC 2D texture using `Map`/`Unmap`. You can then render a full-screen quad using your DYNAMIC 2D texture to get it into the render target backbuffer in the DXGI swapchain, and then `Present` to swap the buffers.

See [How to: Use dynamic resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn508285.aspx)

> You can use `SpriteBatch` in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) to do the 'full-screen quad render' trick of your DYNAMIC texture.

Comment: In addition to textures, could also use the vertex buffer or a cbuffer (or any of the other buffers really)

Comment: If the OP wants to render the result of a 'software rendererer', this is probably the fastest way rather than drawing ``width * height`` points.